# Comma or no comma before "PhD"?

Tags: punctuation

Which is correct in citing someone's name who has a PhD: "John Doe PhD" or "John Doe, PhD"?

Answer (score 5):

According to a few [online summaries](https://www.codot.gov/business/grants/safetygrants/documents/APStyleGuideCheatSheet.pdf) of the AP Style Guide publicly available, abbreviations for degrees should be set off with commas. So **John Doe, Ph.D.** would be correct.

Comment: +1 for remembering to instruct the periods in Ph.D.

Answer (score 2):

There was a television series in the 1960s entitled "Marcus Welby, M.D." Lawyers of a certain age have long written "John Doe, Esquire" on their business cards. Based on these analogies, I have long written "John Doe, PhD."